# heroku deploy and view a node.js app

Tags: node.js, github, heroku

I'm getting lost in the heroku documentation but I've basically finished the following steps and now I want to view the webpage showing the app (not on my local machine but on the web).

1) I've used package.json to specify the build of my node.js project
2) I've used a pipeline to connect my github project black-tomcat-dev/heroku-node-test to my main heroku app so once I update my own github repo it updates the main project.
3)  Ive created express.js routing command to get to make a cool page  that creates smileys.

**EDIT How does the pipeline work How can I push code from my black-tomcat-dev repo to the test environment in my main heroku app

This is a heroku, node.js and github question.

Answer (score 0):

[Pipelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines) in Heroku is basically a ***collection of individual Heroku apps***. All the apps literally shares the same code between each other. It is similar to Continuous Delivery. Where it flows like

```
Review --> Development ---> Staging ----> Production
```

1. As you have connected GitHub with Heroku already, for every pull request, Heroku will automatically create an app (here, [review app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps)).
2. When you merge the pull request to master branch in GitHub, Heroku will automatically deploy the branch to Staging.
3. From the staging, you need to promote your app to production. This can be done either from Heroku environment or through command line - `heroku pipelines:promote`

---

Since you have only one app, this doesn't require pipeline. So, once you deploy to Heroku, you can directly open the app using [command line](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#apps-open):

```
heroku open -a <your_app_name_here>
```